# JDO Google App Engine: How do I persist then query List of custom typed object that is a child of a custom typed parent?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm using Objectify to try and persist some custom type Objects and then retrieve them using a query.

How would I persist and then query just the Command objects?

Here are the objects:

```
public class Command {
    @Id private Key key;
    public ArrayList<Section> sections;
}

class Section {
    @Id private Key key;
    public ArrayList<Phrase> phrases;
}

class Phrase {
    public String phrase;
    public String output;
    @Id private Key key;
}
```

Comment: Changed tags from JDO to Objectify since you aren't using JDO. Obviously if you were then it is simple to persist and query a List of persistable objects

Answer (score 0):

Objectify requires that, there must be an @Id field (String, Long, or long) in  your objects (POJO) in order to persist the object into datastore. check out the link below for detailed info regarding persisting and querying

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Create_Your_Entity_Classes